# jQuery setInterval too fast when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When the tab my website is on is inactive, my slideshow starts switching pictures too fast and mess the whole thing up.

Is there a way i could fix this?

```
var img_src = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"];
var delay = 8000;
var first_run = true;

function switch_pic(position){
  $("#show").attr("src", img_src[position]).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  if(first_run){
    switch_pic(i);
    first_run = false;
    i++;
  }
  window.setInterval(function(){
    switch_pic(i);
    delay += 8000;
    i++;
    if(i > 3){   
      i = 0;
      window.clearInterval();
    }
  }, delay);
});
```

Comment: Youre already using jQuery. Just use [jQuery Cycle or Cycle lite](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/); No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: It looks promising, I'll have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Yep it works like a charm. TYVM

Answer (score 0):

Could wrap the code in this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
       //code run when tab is selected
    }).focusin(function(){
       //code to stop all animation
    });
});
```

That would only let the slideshow run when the user is viewing your site.

Comment: Wouldnt he need to bind some kind of "stop" on `focusout`?

Comment: It doesn't work, it made things about 5 times faster than they were.

Comment: @JamesCoyle it should be `.focusin` and `.focusout` function IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why things speed up. Normally the timers on background tabs will be slowed down to at least one second, but this shouldn't affect your scenario. I suggest using console.log() to track the calls to your functions.

Also, you can simplify your main loop a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  window.setInterval(function(){
    switch_pic(i++); // increase i after call
    if(i > 3) i = 0; // reset i
  }, 8000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer good for actual version of jQuery should look like this:

```
    var intervalId;

    $([window, document]).on('focusin', function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            // Action in interval
        }, 3000);
    }).on('focusout', function(){
        if (intervalId) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    });
```

Pleas remember, that first time your `'focusin'` is not tigger when page is loaded, so you should use this construction for this:

```
intervalFunction();

$([window, document]).on('focusin', function(){
    if (!intervalId){
        intervalFunction();
    }
}).on('focusout', function(){
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = undefined;
    }
});

function intervalFunction() {
    // Your function hire
}
```